# Has anyone used Hedera Hashgraph? Is it really as fast as 100 ~ 10000/s for transactions?

Tags: blockchain, distributed-system, consensus, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

I have researched some articles and videos as bellow, but want to hear more opinions.

https://hedera.com/hh_whitepaper_v2.1-20200815.pdf
https://blog.eccouncil.org/hashgraph-vs-blockchain-top-4-differences-you-need-to-know/

this video is saying the 10000 per second is not accurate
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIyL3d68Cg0

Answer (score 2):

The Hedera mainnet has been [proven by Adsdax](https://coinrivet.com/adsdax-achieves-1372-cryptocurrency-transactions-per-second-on-hedera-hashgraph-with-zee-entertainment-enterprises-sets-new-industry-record/) in the wild to scale to *at least* 1,372 transactions per second. I'm sure the network has topped out at higher since its opening in 2019.

You can see the currently throttled tps limits on the mainnet in [Hedera docs](https://docs.hedera.com/guides/mainnet). This peaks at 8,000 tps currently for Hedera Consensus Service messages which is the majority of transaction on Hedera today. You could, of course, test this out for yourself if you like.

Important to note, this is different then smart contract transactions which are limited by EVM performance and also pre-sharding, which is on [Hedera's roadmap](https://hedera.com/roadmap) for the end of 2021 and would additionally increase the tps capacity well beyond the 10k figure.

Overall, a lot of the claims the youtube video you have linked has been debunked in quite detail by the Hedera community in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hashgraph/comments/l85ozo/the_many_mistakes_made_by_guy_coin_bureau_in_his/).

Full disclosure: I work at Hedera.